# What module is the unnamed package part of in Java?

Tags: java

I think that the unnamed package is part of the unnamed module, however I can't be sure as I can't find any answers online, so I posted my question here.

> *From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/createpkgs.html*:
>
> If you do not use a package statement, your type ends up in an unnamed package. Generally speaking, an unnamed package is only for small or temporary applications or when you are just beginning the development process. Otherwise, classes and interfaces belong in named packages.

*Edit: The answer is that the unnamed package is part of the unnamed module

Comment: Can you provide more information for us to understand what code you're running for your problem, as well as what exactly you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: My question is a general question about the Java programming language, it involves no code at all.

Comment: I'm not sure how accurate this is, or if it answers your question fully, but this page goes into depth about unnamed modules: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/modules/unnamed-modules.html There is a really cool way to describe modules in the middle.. Once I've run, if it is of any value and answers your question I'll post an answer

Comment: The edit you made to my question answered the question, thank you.

Comment: Great! Can you add an answer to this question to describe the final answer and mark it as answered for future visitors of this question?

Answer (score 2):

It is in a (the) unnamed module.

According to the Java 11 edition of the [JLS 7.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4.2)

> The host system must associate ordinary compilation units in an unnamed package with an unnamed module (§7.7.5), not a named module.

This is more authoritative than the Java Tutorial.