# create-runtime-image goal failed using Moditect

Tags: java, maven, jlink, moditect

I want to generate a `module-info.java` and create a runtime image for my java project in Windows.
I'm using Moditect (https://github.com/moditect/moditect), and this is my `pom.xml` so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>jaryjay</groupId>
    <artifactId>moditect-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <native.target>natives-windows</native.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.moditect/moditect-maven-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.moditect</groupId>
            <artifactId>moditect-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <compilerArg>--module-path</compilerArg>
                        <compilerArg>${project.build.directory}/modules</compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>app.HelloWorld</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.moditect</groupId>
                <artifactId>moditect-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-module-info</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate-module-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <modules>
                                <module>
                                    <artifact>
                                        <groupId>jaryjay</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>moditect-test</artifactId>
                                        <version>0.0.1</version>
                                    </artifact>
                                    <moduleInfo>
                                        <name>jaryjay.moditectTest</name>
                                        <exports>
                                            *;
                                        </exports>
                                        <requires>
                                        </requires>
                                        <opens>
                                        </opens>
                                        <opensResources>
                                        </opensResources>
                                        <uses>
                                        </uses>
                                        <provides>
                                        </provides>
                                        <addServiceUses>true</addServiceUses>
                                    </moduleInfo>
                                </module>
                            </modules>
                            <jdepsExtraArgs>
                            </jdepsExtraArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-runtime-image</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create-runtime-image</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <modulePath>
                                <path>${project.build.directory}/modules</path>
                            </modulePath>
                            <modules>
                                <module>jaryjay.moditectTest</module>
                            </modules>
                            <launcher>
                                <name>launcherTestJay</name>
                                <module>jaryjay.moditectTest</module>
                            </launcher>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/jlink-image
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I keep getting this error when running `mvn clean install`:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.moditect:moditect-maven-plugin:1.0.0.RC1:create-runtime-image (create-runtime-image) on project moditect-test: Execution create-runtime-image of goal org.moditect:moditect-maven-plugin:1.0.0.RC1:create-runtime-image failed: Execution of jlink failed
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution create-runtime-image of goal org.moditect:moditect-maven-plugin:1.0.0.RC1:create-runtime-image failed: Execution of jlink failed
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Execution of jlink failed
    at org.moditect.internal.command.ProcessExecutor.run (ProcessExecutor.java:68)
    at org.moditect.commands.CreateRuntimeImage.runJlink (CreateRuntimeImage.java:126)
    at org.moditect.commands.CreateRuntimeImage.run (CreateRuntimeImage.java:72)
    at org.moditect.mavenplugin.image.CreateRuntimeImageMojo.execute (CreateRuntimeImageMojo.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

This is my project layout.

```
jaryjay-moditect-test
│   .classpath
│   .project
│   pom.xml
│
└───src
    └───main
        └───java
            ├───app
            │       HelloWorld.java
            │
            └───test
                    TestClass.java
```

How do I fix my `pom.xml` so that the `create-runtime-image` goal can successfully create a runtime image?

**EDIT:** I've found that this error is inconsistent if I disable the plugins, run `mvn install`, then re-enable the plugins. Therefore, I have a feeling that this is Moditect's problem. Additionally, Moditect is still really new (latest version is 1.0.0) and I could not find a simple tutorial on it. Because of these reasons, I've decided to stop using Moditect in my project and instead manually create runtime images using `jlink`.

Comment: What happens if you run jlink yourself?

Comment: @tgdavies When I run jlink on a project without maven, it runs just fine. For some reason, I cannot find a module-info.class file in this project, so I don't know how to use jlink on it.

Comment: Create a package too. You can't export *, only named packages. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56313903/what-module-is-the-unnamed-package-part-of-in-java

Comment: @tevemadar Moditect allows you to use   *; Source: https://github.com/moditect/moditect/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Ok, now I see `app` is a package.